# openapi-generator regenerate code with updated openapi-spec for python-flask

Tags: flask, openapi, openapi-generator

So, I have been working on python-flask generated code using openapi-generator, but on updating the api-spec it overwrites all my logic on controllers. Is there any standard way to deal with this?

For example if I want to update the parameter name like from this:

```
/shop/{shopId}:
```

to

```
/shop/{uniqueId}:
```

In this case it will regenerate all my controller files and my logic implemented in them with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using my own custom opeanapi template, with a custom post python script to generate new `impl` files, such that.
Comment below if anyone needs more details.